# What class to store xsl file in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I get xsl file from server and I need to store it in my program under some type. XslCompiledTransform does not take stream as a constructor's argument. Any ideas how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XslCompiledTransform has a method Load(XmlReader).
And you can create a XlReader with metod Create(Stream)

[XslCompiledTransform Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx)

[XmlReader Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: upss sorry.. do you want to say, scheme of xml..lapsus. my fault